# Select within a select within a select within a select within a select

Tags: multi-select

I'm trying to make heads & tails of the reasoning behind multiple select statements within each other.  In other words, what is the point?  NOTE:  I'm pretty familiar with T-SQL...I've been moved from the maintenance aspect of SQL Server to the developing side of it.
Below is the code (in part) that confuses me:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
,NAME
,TypeCode
,ProductId
,ProductName
,LocationCode
,County
,STATE
,RecommendationType
,PackageName
FROM (
SELECT c.Id
    ,C.NAME
    ,p.Typecode
    ,p.ProductId
    ,p.Productname
    ,p.LocationCode
    ,p.County
    ,p.STATE
    ,'Appened' AS RecommendationType
    ,PackageName
FROM (
    SELECT op.*
        ,t.i.value('@ProductId', 'varchar(50)') AS productId
        ,t.i.value('@Name', 'varchar(50)') AS Product
    FROM (
        SELECT pg.CustomerId
            ,pg.NAME AS PackageName
            ,pg.runtimedefinition.query('/PackageDefinition/Products')                                    AS CList
        FROM product.package pg WITH (NOLOCK)
        ) op
    CROSS APPLY clist.nodes('Products/Task[@xsi:type="ProductTask"]') t(i)
    ) m
```

Remember...this code is in part.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Well the second one in seems a tad pointless as it only adds one column populated by a literal, but other than that.

In a previous incarnation it may have done more and re-factoring was deemed too much effort, or maybe suffered from developer amnesia. "I thought I'd done that" 
Manager interruption, go off an fix another bit of code and forget you haven't finished this one.

As for the technique it's a nice way of coming up with a solution. I call it inside out, there's probably a scientific name for it though.

After all the effort put in the cross apply with the xml and getting it working, it's easier to use the result and bolt on extra behaviour by wrapping it up as an inner query.

It's less noisy than a temporary table and possibly developed pre CTEs or by a dev not really comfortable with them .

Try and write it in a oner, you might start seeing a point or two. :)